# Django database design with foreign key

Tags: mysql, django, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a Django app that displays analytics for stock data.  One thing that I would like to show in my analytics is a plot of *current* return (y axis) and risk (x axis) for stocks in the S&P500

There is one table of stock data which is being updated every 2.5 minutes.  It has primary keys symbol and time.  This table currently has ~5 million rows

Currently, I have another table called current_quotes, which has exactly 500 rows at all times.  Current quotes contains just a foreign key to the 500 most recent data points inside the stock data table, containing the information for the current return of 500 stocks.  Essentially this table is a table of pointers to the subset of stock_data that I want to use.  This table is updated every 2.5 minutes at the same time when new stock data is inserted

The way I access the most recent data points for the 500 stocks is done by looping over the rows in current_quotes, and retrieving data in stock_data by looking up the foreign key.  This is pretty slow and takes me roughly 4 minutes to retrieve all the recent data.

Is there another way to do this without using foreign keys?

Comment: I would sugest a last_updated auto_now datetime field combined with `order_by('-last_updated')[500:]`. This way you can have just one table.

Comment: wouldn't sorting it be slower?  I thought having the pointers would give me fast access, even though there is more memory overhead

Comment: If you create an index on the last_updated column this will be VERY fast in any respectable DBMS.

Comment: is it ok to index by last_updated if new data is inserted every few minutes?

Comment: You should not worry about it because: 1) Premature optimization is the root of all evil. 2) Concerns about index performance toll should be left to your DBA. 3) According to my experience this design should perform well, at least with PostgreSQL - let me know if you experience any problem.